# How to get direction in which camera is facing across multiple browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, cross-browser

For an application, I'm trying to write a js that can show us accurately what direction the device camera is pointing. List of things we tried

1. Using Alpha, Beta and Gamma values from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639182/html5-get-device-orientation-rotation-in-relative-coordinate) for a relative co-ordinate system. This gave us different results for every phone which were mostly wrong.
2. Using getOrientationAbsolute, which is not supported in any browser except chrome 50+. Also, it was supported in very few phones.
3. We want to try [three.js](https://threejs.org/) but are not sure what to implement since we do not need anything else, just the deviation of the device camera from north.

[This](http://cool.eu-4.evennode.com) is what has been written till now. If anyone can help with a consistent solution, I'll be very thankful.

Comment: Three.js is not what you want. Three.js can take the results of device position to do AR and VR interactions with 3d environments. What you want is a library that normalizes those wacky Alpha, Beta and Gamma outputs. For example, see https://github.com/adtile/Full-Tilt

Comment: It seems there isn't a standard implementation of compass API that is cross platform and cross browser, so any amount of JS cannot show the direction reliably. I guess we might have to abandon this..