# Adjusting mobile accelerometer data to account for phone rotation

Tags: javascript, angular, mobile, accelerometer

I am looking to record mobile accelerometer data (x/y/z) and adjust it to be consistent irrespective of the orientation/rotation of the phone. The usecase here is to record and normalize these parameters while driving to detect turns/twists etc. A key element of this is to ensure that the reported data is independent of how the phone is oriented in the car. I am using [gyronorm.js](https://github.com/dorukeker/gyronorm.js/) to get the device motion and orientation details.

I've looked at previous answers related to this topic on SO (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36662093/1361529) one) and have tried implementing their approach to get earth coordinates.

However, I am seeing readings completely change as I turn/twist my phone. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is how I am calculating earth coordinates:

```
       const deg2rad = Math.PI / 180;
       let alpha = gdata.do.alpha;
       let beta = gdata.do.beta;
       let gamma = gdata.do.gamma;



       let rotatematrix = this.getRotationMatrix(alpha * deg2rad, beta * deg2rad, gamma * deg2rad);

       let relativeacc = new Array(3);
       let earthacc = new Array(3);
       let inv = new Array(9)
       relativeacc[0] = gdata.dm.gx;
       relativeacc[1] = gdata.dm.gy;
       relativeacc[2] = gdata.dm.gz;

       //console.log ("FIRST MATRIX")
       mat3.invert(inv,rotatematrix);
       //console.log ("SECOND MATRIX")
       mat3.multiply(earthacc, inv, relativeacc);


       let accEarthX = earthacc[0];
       let accEarthY = earthacc[1];
       let accEarthZ = earthacc[2];

        let aMag = Math.sqrt(accEarthX*accEarthX + accEarthY*accEarthY + accEarthZ*accEarthZ)

        console.log (`---RAW DATA --- ` + JSON.stringify(gdata));
        console.log (`*** EARTH DATA X=${accEarthX}, Y=${accEarthY} Z=${accEarthZ}`)
```

This is the `getRotationMatrix` code

```
// credit:https://stackoverflow.com/a/36662093/1361529
getRotationMatrix(alpha, beta, gamma) {

    const getScreenOrientation = () => {
    switch (window.screen.orientation || window.screen.mozOrientation) {
      case 'landscape-primary':
        return 90;
      case 'landscape-secondary':
        return -90;
      case 'portrait-secondary':
        return 180;
      case 'portrait-primary':
        return 0;
    }
    if (window.orientation !== undefined)
      return window.orientation;
  };

  const screenOrientation = getScreenOrientation();
  console.log ("SCREEN ORIENTATIIN = "+screenOrientation);

    let out = [];
    let  _z = alpha;
    let _x = beta;
    let _y = gamma;


    if (screenOrientation === 90) {
      _x = - gamma;
      _y = beta;
    }
    else if (screenOrientation === -90) {
      _x = gamma;
      _y = - beta;
    }
    else if (screenOrientation === 180) {
      _x = - beta;
      _y = - gamma;
    }
    else if (screenOrientation === 0) {
      _x = beta;
      _y = gamma;
    }

    let cX = Math.cos( _x );
    let cY = Math.cos( _y );
    let cZ = Math.cos( _z );
    let sX = Math.sin( _x );
    let sY = Math.sin( _y );
    let sZ = Math.sin( _z );

    out[0] = cZ * cY + sZ * sX * sY,    // row 1, col 1
    out[1] = cX * sZ,                   // row 2, col 1
    out[2] = - cZ * sY + sZ * sX * cY , // row 3, col 1

    out[3] = - cY * sZ + cZ * sX * sY,  // row 1, col 2
    out[4] = cZ * cX,                   // row 2, col 2
    out[5] = sZ * sY + cZ * cY * sX,    // row 3, col 2

    out[6] = cX * sY,                   // row 1, col 3
    out[7] = - sX,                      // row 2, col 3
    out[8] = cX * cY                    // row 3, col 3

  return out
```